# Supabase query for many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, sql, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I am trying to find a proper way to query m2m data using supabase client.

I have three tables:

##### public.sites

| column | format |
| --- | --- |
| id | int8 |
| name | text |

##### auth.users  (supabase auth table)

| column | format |
| --- | --- |
| .. | ... |
| id | uuid |

##### public.members

| left | center |
| --- | --- |
| user_id | uuid foreign key to auth.users.id |
| site_id | int8 foreign key to public.sites.id |

I need to query all the sites given the userid. I made several attempts without any success such as:

```js
const sites = await supabase.from('sites').select('id, name, members(user_id)').eq('members.user_id', user.id);
```

P.s. i also ran

```
alter table members
add constraint pk_user_team primary key (user_id, site_id);
```

based on few posts here on stacksoverflow.

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I need to use an inner join on the table and then filter on user_id:

```js
const sites = await supabase.from('sites').select('*, members!inner(user_id)').eq('members.user_id', user.id)
```

Probably there is a better or more efficient way. Any advice is still welcome!